# CSH If: "Expression Syntax" Error for String Comparison with the value "("

Tags: shell, syntax, scripting, syntax-error, csh

I have a shell if statement as below:

```
if($var1!= $var2) then
    ...  
endif
```

when the value of string var1 is **"("**, I get the following error:

> if: Expression Syntax

I know that ( is a syntactic character and I wonder If there is any walkaround to compare a string value for (

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
if ("$var1" != "$var2") then
  ... 
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a soooo indirect solution to this buggy issue:

```
if(`echo $var1` != `echo $var2`) then
    ...  
endif
```

But still I'd like to receive cooler answers. Thanks.

Comment: The cool answer is "don't program in csh". There is no cooler answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
     #!/bin/tcsh
     set A="a"
     set B="b"
     echo A
     echo B
     echo $A
     echo $B
     echo ${A}
     echo ${B}
     #
     if ( `echo $A` == `echo $B` ) then
     pwd
     else
     date
     endif
     #
     echo " simpler  alternative, i.e. A instead of $A, etc. "
     if ( `echo A` == `echo B` ) then
     pwd
     else
     date
     endif
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).